# Numpy seterr doesn't detect overflow

Tags: python, numpy

According to the documentation (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html), `numpy.seterr` should be able to detect overflow and other numerical errors, but I don't understand why what I'm doing doesn't work. The following should raise an exception, but it doesn't.

```
import sys
import numpy as np


def main():
    np.seterr(all='raise')
    x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=np.uint8)
    for _ in range(9):
        print(x)
        x *= 2


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(f'{sys.version=}')
    print(f'{np.version.full_version=}')
    main()
```

Outputs

```
sys.version='3.8.2 (tags/v3.8.2:7b3ab59, Feb 25 2020, 23:03:10) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]'
np.version.full_version='1.19.3'
[1 2 3 4]
[2 4 6 8]
[ 4  8 12 16]
[ 8 16 24 32]
[16 32 48 64]
[ 32  64  96 128]
[ 64 128 192   0]
[128   0 128   0]
[0 0 0 0]
```

I've tried similar examples with `raise`, `warn`, `print`, as well as datatypes `int8`, `uint8`, `int16`, `uint16`, ..., `uint64` and I can't get this thing to raise an error ever, what am I doing wrong? I'm using Windows 10 if that matters.

Comment: It's not you.  `overflow` warning/error is detected with scalar objects like `np.int8(100)`, but not arrays of the same dtype.   Basically if the default setup does not produce a runtime warning, `seterr` isn't going to change it.

Comment: @hpaulj you may really want to post that as an answer because the current one is practically nonsense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a known issue: it seems that overflows in numpy's operations are treated differently according to the size of the int type.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.seterr(all='raise')
{'divide': 'raise', 'over': 'raise', 'under': 'raise', 'invalid': 'raise'}
>>> np.int(320000) * np.int(320000)
102400000000
>>> np.int8(320000) * np.int8(320000)
0
>>> np.int16(320000) * np.int16(320000)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
FloatingPointError: overflow encountered in short_scalars
>>> np.int32(320000) * np.int32(320000)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
FloatingPointError: overflow encountered in long_scalars
>>> np.int64(320000) * np.int64(320000)
102400000000
```

Comment: The thing is that ```type(np.int(320000))``` tells you ```<class 'int'>```, so it uses Python's built-in integer type. All the others overflow correctly: 64-bit simply works, 32-bt and 16-bt overflow, and the 8-bit one works because the least significant byte of 320000 is actually 0, it would also raise an error if it had to.

Answer (score 5):

It's not you. overflow warning/error is detected with scalar objects like `np.int8(100)`, but not arrays of the same `dtype`. That's usually not useful, but apparently developers consider the time penalty for overflow protection on core array operations to be too large.  It's been discussed in other SO and forums.

`seterr` can change how overflow is acted on - default is a warning.  But it can't force an error when there's no warning.