# change resolution of np.datetime64, but raise on overflows

Tags: python, numpy, datetime

If I have a `datetime64[m]` array, how can I cast it to `datetime64[ms]` and error if it overflows?

E.g.:

```py
np.array(['300000-01-01'], dtype='datetime64[m]').astype('datetime64[ms]')  # ok
np.array(['30000000000-01-01'], dtype='datetime64[m]').astype('datetime64[ms]')  # should error
```

Comment: related: [Numpy seterr doesn't detect overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66015753/10197418), [numpy github issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/8987)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to use the `astype` method and specify the desired dtype as `datetime64[ms]` and after that compare the original array with the casted array to check if any overflow has occurred!

check this out :

```
import numpy as np

array1 = np.array(['300000-01-01'], dtype='datetime64[m]')
array2 = np.array(['30000000000-01-01'], dtype='datetime64[m]')

array1_ms = array1.astype('datetime64[ms]')
array2_ms = array2.astype('datetime64[ms]')

# in this case I'll check overflow
if np.any(array1 != array1_ms):
    raise OverflowError("overflow detected in array1")

if np.any(array2 != array2_ms):
    raise OverflowError("overflow detected in array2")
```

Comment: this does not give the desired result on my system; numpy 1.24.4. in fact, I think this is misleading (therefore the dv...); it does not raise an OverflowError where it should.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* catch a warning if you inspect the conversion for the underlying datatype integer, element by element in scalar form:

```py
import warnings
import numpy as np

a0 = np.array(['300000-01-01'], dtype='datetime64[m]')
a1 = np.array(['30000000000-01-01'], dtype='datetime64[m]')

# minutes to milliseconds is a factor of 60 * 1000
conversion_factor = 60 * 1000

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.filterwarnings('error')
    for arr in a0, a1:
        try:
            arr[0].astype(int) * conversion_factor
        except Warning as e:
            print(arr)
            print('error encountered:', e)

# ['30000000000-01-01T00:00']
# error encountered: overflow encountered in scalar multiply
```

However, this does *not* work for the whole array; the integers just overflow silently there.

What you could do instead is check if conversion back to the original resolution in integer representation gives the same result:

```py
for arr in a0, a1:
    print(arr)
    print(
        arr.astype(int) == arr.astype("datetime64[ms]").astype(int) // conversion_factor
    )
    
# ['300000-01-01T00:00']
# [ True]
# ['30000000000-01-01T00:00']
# [False]
```